# Flutter how to change text color of some word which have @

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a text in string in which I need to change the color of that word which start with @

```
String = "I am tagging @John at the post of @Elvin"
```

So I need to change text color of John and elvin in text.

I try to search but not find any solution for this

Comment: One could write \@rameez when rameez isn't registered user. In that case you won't want to show changed color for \@rameez. Right?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html)

first, we need to split the text into an `Iterable` so we can color each `String` depending on whether it contains a `'@'`

```
final text = "I am tagging @John at the post of @Elvin";
Iterable<String> splitText() {
  return text.split('@').skip(1).map((e) {
    final i = e.indexOf(' ');
    if (i == -1) return ['@$e'];
    return [
      '@${e.substring(0, i)}',
      e.substring(i),
    ];
  }).expand((e) => e);
}
```

The above function returns `(@John,  at the post of , @Elvin)`, we can use this in the `RichText Widget`

Note that we skipped "I am tagging " (`text.split('@').skip(1)`) as it will be added in the `TextSpan` text argument ( `text.split('@').first` )

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: text.split('@').first,
    children: splitText().map(
      (e) => TextSpan(
        text: e,
        style: TextStyle(
        color: e.contains('@') ? Colors.purple: null,
      ),
    )).toList(),
  ),
),
```